# Access to the RoleProvider?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

If I have two tables in my project to have access to such a blog (blog writers access) and one for friends access.
I use if I want the RoleProvider What is the form?

Answer (score 0):

This question is very ambiguous and suggestions you need to do some reading on ASP.NET membership/roles... but to check if the user is in a role, you just do this:

`User.IsInRole("role name")`

Answer (score 0):

`Roles.Provider` gets the default Role Provider.

`Roles.Providers` gets the collection of Role Providers for the ASP.NET application.

Look into the `System.Web.Security` namespace